# Ember Disable button while an action is completing its process

Tags: ember.js

> template

```
{{input type="email" value=email placeholder="email"}}
<button {{action "addUser"}} type="submit">Add</button>
```

> controller

```
export default Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        addUser: function(){
            //some codes here
            $.ajax({
                //some codes here
            }).then(()=>{
                alert("success");
            });
        }
    }
});
```

When I call press the button and call the function `addUser` I need to disable the button until the whole function is finished execution

Please help..!

Comment: What did you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways of doing that.

#### First - maintain state manually

This means you should have a property on your controller and set it to `true` when task is running

```
export default Controller.extend({
    actions: {
        addUser: function(){
            this.set('addUserRunning', true);
            //some codes here
            $.ajax({
                //some codes here
            }).then(()=>{
                alert("success");
            }).always(() => {
                this.set('addUserRunning', false);
            });
        }
    }
});

{{input type="email" value=email placeholder="email"}}
<button type="submit" disabled={{addUserRunning}} {{action "addUser"}}>Add</button>
```

#### Second (recommended by me) - use ember-concurrency

There is an addon called ember-concurrency. You need to look through the [docs](http://ember-concurrency.com/docs/tutorial/refactor) to understand how to use it. Instead of action you will use task and task has properties for it's state.

It will be something like this:

```
import { task } from 'ember-concurrency';

export default Controller.extend({
    addUser: task(function* () {
        //some codes here
        yield $.ajax({
           //some codes here
        });
        alert("success");
    }).drop()
});

{{input type="email" value=email placeholder="email"}}
<button type="submit" disabled={{addUser.isRunning}} onclick={{perform addUser}}>Add</button>
```